# read each line of two files and write to a file with a special char to another file in UNIX

Tags: unix

I have two files

abc.txt

```
abc

def

ghi
```

123.txt

```
123

456

789
```

I wanted this output written to another file:

```
abc -> 123

def -> 456

ghi -> 789
```

Answer (score 0):

Repair your solution with `sed`:

```
paste -d '-' abc.txt 123.txt -> abc123.txt | sed 's/-/->/'
```

When '-'can be a character in abc.txt, choose another char that will be unique.

Or use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$1;next} {print $1 " -> " a[FNR] }' 123.txt abc.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `lam` then :

```
lam abc.txt -s "->" 123.txt
```

will do it.